# Solving equations for very large numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm running into a problem where I can't evaluate the following:
$x*(cos(x^2)) - x(cos(x))=36893488147419103231$
in wolfram alpha or sage. Are there any alternatives that I could use to help me? Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

EDIT: My apologies. This is a question I made up out of personal curiosity. I came up with the number from the following sum: $$\sum_{i=0}^{64} 2^n = {36893488147419103231}$$ P.S. I was off by one earlier, my bad.

Comment: How many solutions are there?

Comment: With PARI/GP, I found the solution $$253017600999291974793.642123761\cdots$$

Comment: Is there some context that we might be able to use to help you?

Comment: How did you arrive at this equation ?

Comment: I didn't know PARI/GP was a thing. That's cool, thanks! And truly sorry for being vague, I tried to add some additional detail.

Comment: The smallest positive $x$ should be very close to the big number on the right-hand side (let's call it $A$) divided by $2$. This is because if you plot $\cos x^2-\cos x$ at such large $x$, it becomes randomly valued in $[-2,2]$. The amplitude $x$ then determines when the oscillating function can possibly reach the big number $A$. After that there's still infinitely many more solutions because $\cos x^2-\cos x$ crosses $0$ infinitely many times. Of course, there are negative solutions, too.

Comment: Might be worth noting that $\sum_{i=0}^{64} 2^i = 2^{65} -1$ ;)

Comment: Wow, thanks everyone. I didn't realize until now I was asking a silly question and a bunch of very smart people replied. I like all the responses.